# Worklight features are not working in Blackberry 6

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, command-prompt, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-webworks

I have created a Blackberry 6 project on worklight platform.I used Webwork SDK in order to package the project.But once I tried to run project on Blackberry 6 simulator wlCommonInit()was not being executed.

I packaged my code using command prompt but not with Ripple Emulator.So i didn't packaged the whole code i just packaged native folder of the code.Since Blackberry requires config file and index file to be in the root folder of the zip file I copy pasted the index file outside the default folder and also changed the paths of the script files. 
So is it a because of the pasting the index file outside the default folder that I am getting this error or is it because of the config file not defined properly.

NOTE:My project is a single page html

This is my config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:rim="http://www.blackberry.com/ns/widgets"              version="1.0" rim:backButton="exit">  

  <name>sampleBlack</name>  
    <description>sampleBlack</description>  
    <author email="application author's e-mail">application's author</author>  
    <feature id="worklightFeature" required="false" version="1.0.0"/>  
    <feature id="blackberry.ui.dialog" version="1.0.0"/>  
    <feature id="blackberry.ui.menu" version="1.0.0"/>  
    <feature id="blackberry.invoke" version="1.0.0"/>  
    <feature id="blackberry.invoke.BrowserArguments" version="1.0.0"/>  
    <feature id="blackberry.identity" version="1.0.0"/>  
    <feature id="blackberry.app" version="1.0.0"/>  
    <feature id="blackberry.app.event" version="1.0.0"/>  
    <access subdomains="true" uri="*"/>  
    <content src="www/skinLoader"/>  
    <icon rim:hover="false" src="icon.png"/>  
    <rim:loadingScreen backgroundImage="" foregroundImage="splash.png" onLocalPageLoad="false" onFirstLaunch="true"/> 
</widget>
```

This is my index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html>
    <head>
        <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <META content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>index</title>
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" name="viewport">
        <link href="www/default/worklight/worklight.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="www/default/images/favicon.png" rel="shortcut icon">
        <link href="www/default/images/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon">
        <link href="www/default/css/common-controls.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="www/default/css/android-controls.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="www/default/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="www/default/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="www/default/css/classic.css" id="usertypecss" rel="stylesheet">
        <script>
        // Define WL namespace.
        var WL = WL ? WL : {};
        /**
         * WLClient configuration variables.
         * Values are injected by the deployer that packs the gadget.
         */
        WL.StaticAppProps = {
   "APP_DISPLAY_NAME": "sampleBlack",
   "APP_ID": "sampleBlack",
   "APP_SERVICES_URL": "http:\/\/192.168.0.188:10080\/SampleTest1\/apps\/services\/",
   "APP_VERSION": "1.0",
   "ENVIRONMENT": "blackberry",
   "LOGIN_DISPLAY_TYPE": "embedded",
   "WORKLIGHT_PLATFORM_VERSION": "6.1.0.00.20140123-1934",
   "WORKLIGHT_ROOT_URL": "http:\/\/192.168.0.188:10080\/SampleTest1\/apps\/services\/api\/sampleBlack\/blackberry\/"
};</script>
        <script src="www/default/www/default/worklight/wljq.js"></script>
        <script src="www/default/worklight/worklight.js"></script>
        <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
            <script src="www/default/js/libs/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>           
            <script src="www/default/js/libs/knockout-2.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="www/default/js/libs/knockout.mapping-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="www/default/js/libs/sammy.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="www/default/js/libs/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
            <script src="www/default/js/libs/jquery.iosslider.js"></script>
            <script>
            var MyParentPage="#menu";
            var checkfooter=0;
            var checkhash=0;
            </script>
            <script src="www/default/ViewModels/login/loginViewModel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="www/default/ViewModels/AccountsViewModel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="www/default/ViewModels/TPTViewModel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="www/default/ViewModels/DebitcardViewModel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="www/default/ViewModels/BillPay.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="www/default/ViewModels/DematViewModel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="www/default/ViewModels/MFViewModel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="www/default/ViewModels/CreditViewModel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="www/default/ViewModels/OthersViewModel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">        
            <div class="back nobg">
                <a class="back" data-bind="visible: backVisible" href="javascript:void(0);" id="bv"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="logout nobg">
                <a class="logout" href="#logout" style="display:none;"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="logo">
                <img align="absmiddle" alt="" src="www/default/img/logo_img.png">
            </div>    
            <h1 class="h_title">Login</h1>         
        </div>
        <section class="dynamic-page-content" id="contentData"></section>
        <div class="footer" onclick="return false;" style="display:none;">
            <div class="even alignc" id="save" style="overflow:hidden;font-size:14px;display:none;"> 
                <span class="info_row_left" style="margin:0 auto; display:table; float:none;"><a class="opurl button" href="#" id="#rrper01" style="margin:5px;">Personalize</a></span>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer_nav">
                <ul>
                    <li class="active" id="mymenuI">
                        <a class="icon_menu tt" href="#mymenu"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="rrasm01I">
                        <a class="icon_account tt" href="#rrasm01"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="rrftr01I">
                        <a class="icon_fundTrans tt" href="#rrftr01"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="rrblp01I">
                        <a class="icon_billpay tt" href="#rrblp01"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="r1I">
                        <a class="icon_more" href="javascript:void(0);"></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li id="rracs01I">
                        <a class="icon_credit " href="#rracs01"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="DematI">
                        <a class="icon_demat" href="#Demat"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="debithomeI">
                        <a class="icon_debit" href="#debithome"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="rrwcm01I">
                        <a class="icon_mf" href="#rrwcm01"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li id="othersI">
                        <a class="icon_otheropt" href="#others"></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="www/default/js/theme.js"></script>
            <script src="www/default/js/initOptions.js"></script>
            <script src="www/default/js/main.js"></script>
            <script src="www/default/js/messages.js"></script>
            <script src="www/default/js/appState.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="www/default/js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    function callper(){
        window.location.hash = "#rrper01";
    }
</script>
    </body>
</html>


And this is how my folder which I zip to get cod file looks like
http://50.17.252.160/test/Capture.PNG [sorry about uploading it on server i dont have required reputation to add a pic]
```

I would also appreciate if there are any sample projects available for worklight Blackberry 6 using webWork SDK.

Comment: So you did not follow the guide, and you altered the project structure...

Comment: The ripple emulator was not working and so had to do these changes in order to make it run.I would really appreciate an alternative for ripple emulator also.Thank you

Comment: Whatever BlackBerry provides (see their documentation @ blackberry.com), that's what you can use.

Comment: I followed the blackberry documentation .It requires the config.xml file and index file to be at the root of the zip folder.So referring that i changed my project structure

Answer (score 0):

No folder structure changes are required in order to get a BlackBerry 6/7 app to work, in either Ripple or BlackBerry Simulator/physical device.

If you have the correct WebWorks SDK for BlackBerry 6/7 installed, Worklight Studio will generate a project template that is ready to be used.

See the instructions in this tutorial: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/hello-world/previewing-application-blackberry-6-7/

To download and setup the BlackBerry enviornment, see this tutorial: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/setting-up-your-development-environment/setting-blackberry-6-7-development-environment/

To further debug your issue, it'd be best to provide any available logs from the simulator/device.